Algorithm for separating nodes based on edge weight
I need an algorithm that separates all nodes in an undirected graph into two subgraphs so nodes with heavily-weighted edges are in different subgraphs.
Input example:
A - B (Weight = 3)
A - C (Weight = 2)
A - D (Weight = 3)
B - C (Weight = 1)
B - D (Weight = 1)
C - D (Weight = 1)

Two Groups
AB CD = 3 + 1 = 4
BC AD = 1 + 3 = 4
AC BD = 2 + 1 = 3

AC BD is chosen because it minimizes the sum of edge weights between the nodes within the same group. This is a simple example, but if I were to add more nodes and edges, the output would be two lists of nodes that represent the subgraphs. The resulting subgraphs do not have any specific requirements other than that they must have the same amount of nodes and each node can only appear in one of the two subgraphs.
I've researched but cannot find anything similar to this. Even if there is not an existing algorithm for this I am looking for similar resources to create one

What's the expected output?

you're  grouping edges, not nodes.

is there a requirement that each group has ends on every node?

Do the subgraphs need to be fully connected?

I think you got your work cut out for you. Apparently even the minimum bisection problem is NP-hard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut

IIUC, you want a min_weight_matching. With python, you can do :
import networkx as nx

edges = [
    ("A", "B", {"weight": 3}),
    ("A", "C", {"weight": 2}),
    ("A", "D", {"weight": 3}),
    ("B", "C", {"weight": 1}),
    ("B", "D", {"weight": 1}),
    ("C", "D", {"weight": 1}),
]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

nx.min_weight_matching(G) # {("A", "C"), ("D", "B")}



That's close to what I want, but if I have more nodes, it makes pairs of nodes and I only want two groups. Would it work if I repeatedly use this, merging edges of grouped nodes until there only remains two groups?

Not sure I follow you. Can you update your example and provide the matching expected output ?
